# Fatal error: Class Abhi_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I am getting Error in my model 
 Fatal error: Class Abhi_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

I have implemented saving form data from front end in controller file as follows

```
<?php
class Abhi_Test_User_ViewController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        public function historyAction() {
            echo "Hello it is abhilash";
            $this->loadLayout();    /*This function read all layout files and loads                               them in memory */
            $this->renderLayout();  /* This function processes and displays all layout                             phtml and php files */

        }

        public function savetestAction() {
            $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
            $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
            $content = $_REQUEST['content'];
            $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
            try{
                $model = Mage::getModel('test/test');
                $model->setTitle($title);
                $model->setFilename($filename);
                $model->setContent($content);
                $model->setStatus($status);
                $model->setCreatedTime(strtotime(‘now’));
                $model->setUpdatedTime(strtotime(‘now’));
                $model->save();
            } catch(Exception $e) {

            }
            $this->_redirectSuccess('test/user_view/table');
        return $this;
        }

        public function tableAction() {
            $this->loadLayout();    /*This function read all layout files and loads                               them in memory */
            $this->renderLayout();  /* This function processes and displays all layout                             phtml and php files */
        }

    }
?>
```

This my model class file where i am getting error

```
<?php
class Abhi_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
    public function _contruct() {
        $this->_init('test/test', 'test_id');   /*here test_id is the primary of the table test. And test/test, is the magento table name as mentioned in the config.xml */
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function loadByField($field, $value) {
        $table = $this->getMainTable();
        $where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field = ?", $value);
        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($table, array('test_id'))->where($where);
        $id = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($sql);
        return $id;
    }

}
?>
```

Please tell me if I am doing this correct. My from I have put in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rename

```
public function _contruct() {
```

to

```
protected function _construct() 
{
```

because of `\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_construct` declared as abstract.

The error is telling you that this function is missing in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `parent::__construct();` it does nothing anyway.

Comment: Ok but whats the solution for the error sir

Comment: this should solve your problem also...I think